# How to detect wrapped plain text and apply html markup using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The function of the jquery code I currently have is to detect text enclosed with parenthesis and it will serve as a text anchor to a link.

The problem is that parenthesis appears on the text anchor too. Is it possible to show only the text? Also if it's possible to change the parenthesis() into brackets []. thanks in advance.

```js
$("body").html($("#wrapper").html().replace(/(\([^)]+\))/, "<a href='https://www.sample-url-here.com/'>$1</a>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">text (link here)</div>
```

The outcome I need should be:

```
from text [link here] to text <a href="https://www.sample-url-here.com/">link here</a>
```

Comment: Haven't checked this, but looks like your regex might be wrong. You're missing an escape for the right-paren: `[^\)]`

Comment: @lxe: No, they don't need to be escaped in character classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22ahqLyj/))

```
$("body").html($("#wrapper").html().replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, "[<a href='https://www.sample-url-here.com/'>$1</a>]"));
```

This will output a link surrounded by square brackets, with only the link underlined.

The problem with you original regular expression was that it was looking for anything *not* parentheses, surrounded by anything that *is* parenthesis, and that whole expression was surrounded by capturing parentheses.

In other words, let's look at it like this:

```
(x)
```

We'll call those your **capturing parentheses**. *x* can later be selected with **$1**.

```
x = \([^)]+\)
```

See the problem? Your entire *x* was being captured.

## EDIT

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22ahqLyj/1/) updated to not show brackets.

## EDIT

How about this one? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22ahqLyj/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) The orig code detects parenthesis enclosed text, what I need is to change the parenthesis into a bracket. The text inside the bracket will now converted into a text with link, but should not show the bracket.

Comment: @wjR., no problem, I'm glad it worked. If it solved your problem, remember to click the checkmark to accept the answer!

Comment: We are getting closer! Instead of (parenthesis), it should be wrapped with [bracket]. The reason is that parenthesis is very common when writing a post, so better if we use bracket instead. thanks for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: @wjR., the first jsfiddle has it with brackets. The second one has it without brackets. Which one do you want, brackets or no brackets?

Comment: The second is better because it doesnt show the parenthesis into the anchor text. But I mentioned about bracket to be used to detect a text we need to add a link.

Comment: You got it right sir! you saved my day! thank you :)

Comment: I encountered another problem, the code doesn't support multiple instances of enclosed texts.